# How to build libudev from source?

Tags: build, systemd, meson-build, libudev

I am trying to build `libudev` from source, since I would like to make it a conan package. Current conan package only installs `libudev` from apt repository.

I have found the sources under the `systemd` library [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd) since original source was merged into it.

I cloned the `systemd` repository, but only possibility to build it is to build either the whole `systemd` or to heavily edit `meson.build` file.

Is there any other (easier) way to build `libudev` from source, or do I have to edit the `meson.build` file?